# Custom EDM Mapping not used runtime

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying migrate from EF5 to EF6.
After installing EF6 package, I updated required namespaces & *.tt files but then when I tried to update model from database, encountered certain type mapping errors which turned out to be due to change in default number mapping in EF6. 
I am using oracle provider so as per oracle docs I added custom mapping configuration. 
Now my designer works fine, able to update model from database but when I execute my code, it fails with the same error.

```
error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 'Edm.Int16[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=]' of member <PROPERTY> in type 'Model.<ENTITY>' is not compatible with 'OracleEFProvider.number[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,Precision=3,Scale=0]' of member <PROPERTY> in type Model.Store.<ENTITY>
```

Oracle Docs
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63277_01/win.121/e63268/entityDataTypeMapping.htm#ODPNT8303

Configuration

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
      <version number="*">
               <edmMappings>

                   <edmNumberMapping>
                    <add NETType="int16" MinPrecision="1" MaxPrecision="5" DBType="Number" />
                    <add NETType="int32" MinPrecision="6" MaxPrecision="10" DBType="Number" />
                    <add NETType="int64" MinPrecision="11" MaxPrecision="19" DBType="Number" />
                  </edmNumberMapping>
        </version>
</oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

I tried below configuration as well

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
     <version number="*">
       <edmMappings> 
          <edmMapping dataType="number">
            <add precision="1" name="int16" />
            <add precision="3" name="int16" />
            <add precision="5" name="int16" />
            <add precision="10" name="int32" />
            <add precision="19" name="int64" />
          </edmMapping>
       </edmMappings>
     </version></oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

I am at it for a couple of days now but couldn't figure out why the custom mapping is being ignored at run time.

```
supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
```

Thoughts?